# Error: an attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (0x8007000B) C# ASP.NET MVC new project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to start a new ASP.NET MVC web app project in Visual Studio 2022 and when trying to build the project with the predefined starting code, I get this error:

[image: Output].

I have tried to set the Platform target to various targets and I have enabled 32-bit applications in IIS Manager and it's still giving me the error, I'm unable to build a brand new ASP.NET MVC project.

My system type: x64-based PC.

Comment: Did you introduce any kind of dependencies using nuget? Or have you literally just created this new project and nothing else ?

Comment: Please post the code or error into your question, not an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think you might have a conflict between 32 / 64 bit architecture. From the `Menu Bar` click on `Tools` -> `Options`. Under the dialog box Under `Project and Solutions` select `Web Projects` and on the right side. Check the `Use 64 bit version of IIS...`